# Splitting an ffdf object

Tags: r, ff, ffbase

I'm using `ff` and `ffbase` libraries to manage a big csv file (~40Go and 275e6 observations). I'd like to split/partition this file according to one of its columns (which is a factor column).

With a normal data frame, I would do something like that:

```
a <- data.frame(rnorm(10000,0,1),
                sample(1:100,10000,replace=T),
                sample(letters,10000,replace = T))
names(a) <- c('V1','V2','V3')
a_partition <- split(a,a$V3)
names(a_partition) <- paste("df",names(a_partition),sep = "_")
list2env(a_partition,globalenv())
```

but `ff` and `ffbase` doesn't have a `split` function. So, looking in the `ffbase` documentation, I found `ffdfply` and tried to use it as follows:

```
ffa <- as.ffdf(a)
ffa_partititon <- ffdfdply(x = ffa,split = ffa$V3)
```

Alas, I get the log message :

> calculating split sizes
>    building up split locations
>    working on split 1/1, extracting data in RAM of 26 split elements,
>        totalling, 0.00015 GB, while max specified
>        data specified using BATCHBYTES is 0.01999 GB
>      ... applying FUN to selected data
>      Error: argument "FUN" is missing, with no default

I tried `FUN = as.data.frame` (since the result of the function must be a data frame) with no luck : doing so makes ffa_partition a copy of ffa...

How can I partition my ffdf?

Comment: Hi, if you look at the help of `ffdfapply`, you will see there is a third mandatory argument `FUN` which you miss in your call, hence the error message. I would try FUN=as.data.frame

Comment: @Eric Lecoutre : yes, I tried that but it does nothing (literally, it return the ffdf I put in the entry...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two years late, but I believe this does what you needed:

```
result_list <- list()
for(letter in letters){
    result_list[[letter]] <- subset(ffa, V3 == letter)
}
```